# Можно ли добавить 2-й массив в цикл for?

Tags: python, for

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b=['a','b','c']

for i in a,b:
    print(str(a)+"swap"+b)`
```

Как добавить 2-й массив в цикл `for`?

Comment: Что должно получиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Но:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b=['a','b','c']

for i in a,b:
    print(i)

[1, 2, 3]
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

То есть перечисление через запятую воспринимается как итерируемый объект. Но вы ведь не эту цель преследовали...

```
a = [1,2,3]
b=['a','b','c']
c = zip(a,b)
for i, j in c:
    print(str(i) + "swap" + j)

1swapa
2swapb
3swapc
```

Answer (score 2):

как вариант, можно и совсем без цикла обойтись:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b=['a','b','c']
print(*map(lambda x,y: f'{x}swap{y}', a,b),sep='\n')
```

вывод:

```
1swapa
2swapb
3swapc
```